# Missing faces while exporting from Blender to Unity even though the face orientation is correct

Tags: faces

I tried to find a solution to this and came across multiple posts that was about the same problem, and even though they mentioned their face orientations were correct/they tried recalculating the normals, it seems like none of these who answered didn't read the post at all and suggested the (recalculating normals) "fix".

Anyway, I wanted to update my car mesh and added some faces to the exhaust, however even with correct orientation the faces were not visible at all.

in Blender (ignore the opposite sided face in the back, it has nothing to do with the exhaust):
[image: in Blender]

in Unity:

[image: in Unity]

I don't think the faces are self intersecting either, all faces are quads:

[image: faces]

I'm also certain that the mesh is being updated, the other changes I made to the car are visible.

Comment: If you inspect the mesh in Unity as a wireframe, do you see the added exhaust faces or arent they are exported at all?

Comment: Now that's interesting, there are actually no faces at all. The faces are all quads so I don't think there are any self-intersecting polygons (I actually get a few "self-intersecting polygon" errors while importing, but they are always there and I don't mind them since there are no invisible faces that are significant). What do you think it could be?

Comment: Hard to tell. Some things to try: triangulate the offending quads before export, check if they have another material and if that material is imported, disable any optimization in the importer settings of the model in Unity. Can you share your model or at least the exhaust part?